# How do I get my wcf service to update when I use the WCF Test Client?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf, wcftestclient

I have created a basic wcf service nothing more complicated than helloworld. I have tested it with both WCF Test Client and my own client app and it works fine.

So with that I wanted to add a method to it to see if I might try something a bit more complicated. However now when I try to debug using the WCF Test Client my new method doesn't show up the only method that is there is the original one. So I tried removing the original method completely and test again and it is still there and my new method is still missing.

So it is apparent that my modified service isn't updating whatever the WCF Test Client is using to test against.

Where are the temporary files that VS 2008 generates to allow the WCF Test Client to work. Or could someone explain to me how to refresh the service when I modify it.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

Did you build your modified service? If you don't build it, then there's nothing to update.

Comment: Yes I commpletely deleted the debug and release .dlls and rebuilt, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you new service and you service interface are properly decorated with the `OperationContract` attribute.

Update: Take a look at the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx), and see if you can get the operation to show up using this?

Comment: I have my interface looks like this.
   
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorld
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetLink(string uname);

        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string inputName);

        
    }

Comment: I added an update.  btw, in the future, code updates are best received as an update to your original question.

Comment: Thanks for the update and I will keep that in mind about future questions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both of the solution above without success though I appreciate both answers as they are very good things to check.

The answer I found that ended up fixing the problem was to simply update the version number on the project. I don't know why this fixed it, but after I did my new methods showed up and have continued to show up for each build since.

It would appear that this might be a bug in VS 2008.

Comment: It was not version number, unless changing any arbitrary bit would have helped. Version number is not a concept that is exposed outside the service. The WCF Test Client could not have seen the version number.

Comment: I'm not saying the WCF Test Client was what was having the problem. For some reason Visual Studio wouldn't create a new debug compile until I versioned up. I think the WCF Test Client was working with exactly what Visual Studio was giving it. Thats why I think it is a VS bug not a WCF Test Client bug.